# Find and replace a specific reference pattern by a regular expression (no.2)

Tags: regex

Today, I was very happy that I get a solution for my first post here: [Find and replace a specific reference pattern by a regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29717966/find-and-replace-a-specific-reference-pattern-by-a-regular-expression/29718167?noredirect=1#comment47595785_29718167).

I'd like to replace following entries (and many more of these types in my document), so that the (number 1,2,3,4 or 5, only if present, plus) the first three alpha-letters is written in the bracket after textit. The initial expression has to be appended.

Input:

```
\nobreakword{(vgl. 1. Johannes 4,16)}
\nobreakword{(vgl. Daniel 4,15.17.32f.)}    
\nobreakword{(vgl. 2. Könige 7,7)}
```

=> Output:

```
\index[bibel]{@1. Johannes!\textit{1Joh 4,16}}\nobreakword{(vgl. 1. Johannes 4,16)}
\index[bibel]{@Daniel!\textit{Dan 4,15.17.32f.}}\nobreakword{(vgl. Daniel 4,15.17.32f.)}
\index[bibel]{@2. Könige!\textit{2Könige 7,7}}\nobreakword{(vgl. 2. Könige 7,7)}
```

I have also ä/ö/ü characters inside the brackets.

I'd like to include patterns in which the numerical part is written on the next line (because of copy paste) there is an ENTER (space/many blank characters) between the text and numbers.

```
\nobreakword{(vgl. 
    1. Korinther 13,4-7.8-12)}           => \index[bibel]{@1. Korinther!\textit{1Kor 13,4-7.8-12}}\nobreakword{(vgl. 1. Korinther 13,4-7.8-12)}
\nobreakword{(vgl. 1. 
       Korinther 13,4-7.8-12)}           => \index[bibel]{@1. Korinther!\textit{1Kor 13,4-7.8-12}}\nobreakword{(vgl. 1. Korinther 13,4-7.8-12)}
\nobreakword{(vgl. 1. Korinther 
            13,4-7.8-12)}                => \index[bibel]{@1. Korinther!\textit{1Kor 13,4-7.8-12}}\nobreakword{(vgl. 1. Korinther 13,4-7.8-12)}
```

I have other text which should not be changed:

```
\index[stichwort]{Begriffe!Zeichen}      => \index[stichwort]{Begriffe!Zeichen}
\index[stichwort]{Bilder [wörtl./bildhaft:Gleichnis,Symbol/beides]!Personen!Abraham} => \index[stichwort]{Bilder [wörtl./bildhaft:Gleichnis,Symbol/beides]!Personen!Abraham}
```

If possible I'd like again to use https://regex101.com

I tried (without success):
`\\nobreakword{(vgl. (\d+)(?:\.\s+))?(.{3})[\s\S]*?([a-z0-9.,-]+)}`

Is it possible to use a single search pattern + single replace pattern with regular expression to replace all of the examples in one step?

**EDIT**

All names "Johannes", "Daniel", "Könige", "Korinther" etc. are at least 3 characters long.

I like to input following test string:

```
        \chapter{Gottes Liebesbeweis an uns Menschen}

        \begin{flushright}\footnotesize\textit{ursprünglicher Beitrag vom 29. April 2014 überarbeitet}\end{flushright}

        - Gott ist Liebe. \nobreakword{(vgl. 1. Johannes 4,16)}\\
        - Jesus Christus ist der Erstgeborene der gesamten Schöpfung. (vgl. Kolosser 1,15-17) \index[bibel]{51@Kolosser!\textit{Kol 1,15-17}}
        \index[stichwort]{Bilder [wörtl./bildhaft:Gleichnis,Symbol/beides]!Erstgeburt/Erstgeborener}\\
        - Im Anfang, nachdem Jesus war, schuf Gott Himmel und Erde. (vgl.
        1. Mose 1,1)\index[stichwort]{Bilder [wörtl./bildhaft:Gleichnis,Symbol/beides]!Himmel}\\
        - Liebe braucht ein Gegenüber: Gott hat den Menschen geschaffen nach
        dem Bild von Gott, der fähig war, Liebe zu empfinden und zurückzulieben.
        \nobreakword{(vgl. 1. Mose 1,26)}\\
        - Echte Liebe kann nur bedingungslos sein und muss dem Gegenüber erlauben,
        sich gegen die Liebe zu entscheiden. \nobreakword{(vgl. 1. Korinther 13,4-7)}\\
        - Gott erwählte Jesus bereits vor Erschaffung des Menschen, weil ER
        bereits zu Anbeginn der Zeit wusste, dass alle Menschen Unrecht tun
        werden und Rettung benötigen. \nobreakword{(vgl. Epheser 1,3-4)}
        \index[stichwort]{Begriffe!Gerechtigkeit/Gerechtsprechung/Gerechte/ \newline Rechtfertigung}\\
        - Gott kann alles tun, was ER tun möchte \nobreakword{(vgl. Daniel 4,32)}\\
        - Gott erlaubt jedem seiner Geschöpfe die Entscheidung, ob es mit
        IHM - genauer: in IHM - leben möchte oder nicht: Ein Engel Gottes
        in niedriger Stellung in einem der Himmel wollte sich dem Allerhöchsten
        gleich machen in dem dieser Engel zum einen Himmel emporsteigt und
        ist bei diesem Vorgehen hinabgestürzt. \nobreakword{(vgl. Jesaja 14,12-14)}\\
        - Liebe ist bereit ein Risiko einzugehen: Gott überlässt seinen Geschöpfe
        gewisse Entscheidungen. \nobreakword{(vgl. 1. Mose 2,16-17)}\\
        - Der gefallene Engel hatte die Macht Adam und Eva zu versuchen. (vgl.
        1. Mose 3,1)\index[stichwort]{Bilder [wörtl./bildhaft:Gleichnis,Symbol/beides]!Personen!Adam}\\
        - Adam und Eva wollten sein wie Gott, sie wollten dieselbe Erkenntnis
        haben wie Gott. \nobreakword{(vgl. 1.Mose 3,5)}\\
        - Gottes Gedanken, Wege, Weisheit und Erkenntnis sind unbeschreibbar
        viel grösser als die unseren. \nobreakword{(vgl. Römer 11,33)}\index[stichwort]{Bilder [wörtl./bildhaft:Gleichnis,Symbol/beides]!Weg}\\
        - Gott lässt sich nicht über eine bestimmte Anzahl von Bildern definieren;
        Gott spricht: "Ich bin, der ich bin".
        \nobreakword{(vgl. 2. Mose 3,14)}\\
        - Wir haben uns vor Gott getrennt, weil wir selbst unabhängig sein
        wollten, anstatt IHM ganz zu vertrauen und gehorchen. \nobreakword{(vgl. Römer 3,12)}\\
        - Als Folge des Sündenfalls im Garten Eden kam der Tod. \nobreakword{(vgl. Römer 6,23)}\\
        - Die Schöpfungsordnung, dass der Mensch und die Tiere sich von Pflanzen
        ernähren sollte wurde zerstört. \nobreakword{(vgl. 1. Mose 1,29-30)}\\
        - Adam und Eva wurden durch den Ungehorsam Gott gegenüber der Sünde
        Sklave der Sünde. \nobreakword{(vgl. Johannes 8,34)}\\
        - Die Bosheit der Nachkommen Adam und Eva nahm immer weiter zu, dass
        sich nach meiner Auslegung gefallene Engel Gottes mehreren Frauen
        paarten und ihnen Riesen gebaren, wonach auch Gottes Gericht - die
        Sintflut - kam. \nobreakword{(vgl. 1. Mose 6, 1-7)} \index[stichwort]{Begriffe!Zorn/Gericht/Vergeltung/Hölle/Tod}\index[stichwort]{Bilder [wörtl./bildhaft:Gleichnis,Symbol/beides]!Sintflut}\\
        - Alle Menschen sind schuldig geworden, und werden durch den Glauben
        an IHN ohne Verdienst gerecht gesprochen. \nobreakword{(vgl. Römer 3,23-28)}
        \index[stichwort]{Begriffe!Gerechtigkeit/Gerechtsprechung/Gerechte/ \newline Rechtfertigung}\\
        - Jeder Mensch kommt schuldig zur Welt. \nobreakword{\nobreakword{(vgl. Psalm 51,7)}}\\
        - Ein Gläubiger darf bei verstorbenen Säuglingen die Hoffnung haben
        nach dem irdischen Leben wieder bei diesem Menschen zu sein, selbst
        wenn der Säugling zu Lebzeiten nicht die Möglichkeit hatte sich für
        oder gegen Gott zu entscheiden. \nobreakword{(vgl. 2. Samuel 12,21-23)}\\
        - Gott ist vollkommen gerecht. \nobreakword{(vgl. 5. Mose 32,4)}\index[stichwort]{Begriffe!Gerechtigkeit/Gerechtsprechung/Gerechte/ \newline Rechtfertigung}\\
        - Gott kann keine Gemeinschaft mit Sündern haben, sodass es zwischen
        IHM und den Menschen eine Trennung geben musste. \nobreakword{\nobreakword{(vgl. Jesaja 59,2)}}\\
        - Gott möchte eine persönliche Beziehung zu uns Menschen haben. \nobreakword{(vgl.
        Johannes 17,3)}\\
```

Comment: Are all the names at least 3 letters long? Also, it's not quite clear from your questions what your inputs are and what your desired output is...

Comment: Is it right that '2. Könige' => '2Köng'. If so than the abbreviation forms cannot be derived with regular expressions.

Comment: Good catch, @CoronA. My answer produces `2Kön` in that case.

Comment: @CoronA I corrected the typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex:

```
\\nobreakword\{\(vgl\.\s+(([0-9]*)\.\s+)?((\S\S\S)\S*)\s+([^)]*)\)\}
```

And the replacement:

```
\\index[bibel]{@\1 \3!\\textit{\2\4 \5}}\0
```

[On regex101 here.](https://regex101.com/r/gI4vO7/1)

In general, though, this is a terrible way of fixing your references in Latex. You should instead define functions which produce the correct output, so you have a centralized place to edit the formatting when your requirements change.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach was correct.. except for few modifications. You can use :

```
(\\nobreakword{\(vgl\.\s*((\d+)(?:\.\s+))?((.{3}).+?\b)[\s\S]*?([a-z0-9.,-]+)\)})
```

and replace with `\\index[bibel]{@$2$4!\\textit{$3$5 $6}}$1`

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/vK3jA4/3)