# Find and replace a specific reference pattern by a regular expression (no.3)

Tags: regex

I'd like to replace a text pattern `\nobreakword{(....)}`  towards `\href{http://www.bibleserver.com/text/SLT/....}{\nobreakword{(....)}}` in which .... stands for a non-specific text pattern with ä,ö,ü,numbers and ENTERs(new lines))

Input:

```
\nobreakword{(vgl. 1. Johannes 4,16)}
\nobreakword{(Daniel 4,15.17.32f.)}    
\nobreakword{(2. Könige 7,7)}
\nobreakword{(vgl. Römer 2,2)}
```

Sometimes the input .... is broken with an ENTER on two lines:

```
\nobreakword{(
     vgl. 2. Könige 7,7)} 
\nobreakword{(vgl. 2.
     Könige 7,7)}
```

Output:

```
\href{http://www.bibleserver.com/text/SLT/1. Johannes 4,16}{\nobreakword{(vgl. 1. Johannes 4,16)}}
\href{http://www.bibleserver.com/text/SLT/Daniel 4,15.17.32f.}{\nobreakword{(Daniel 4,15.17.32f.)}}
\href{http://www.bibleserver.com/text/SLT/2. Könige 7,7}{\nobreakword{(vgl. 2. Könige 7,7)}}
\href{http://www.bibleserver.com/text/SLT/Römer 2,2}{\nobreakword{(vgl. Römer 2,2)}}
```

If possible I'd like to avoid the `vgl.`  in the URL.

Probably I have to use a group that recognizes the start with `\nobreakword{(` and the ending with `)}`.

Is this possible to do with the use of  https://regex101.com ?

This question has some similarity compared to the old post, but now with the wish to remove the `vgl.` in the URL: [Find and replace a specific reference pattern by a regular expression (no.2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29732375/find-and-replace-a-specific-reference-pattern-by-a-regular-expression-no-2)

Comment: That sounds like a case for a latex macro, not for a regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following to match:

```
(\\nobreakword{\(vgl\.\s*((\d+)(?:\.\s+))?((.{3}).+?\b)[\s\S]*?([a-z0-9.,-]+)\)})
```

And replace with:

```
/\href{http://www.bibleserver.com/text/SLT/$2$4 $6}$1
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/vK3jA4/4)

**Edit:** If there is no restriction on `vgl` you can use:

```
(\\nobreakword{\((?:vgl\.)?\s*((\d+)(?:\.\s+))?((.{3}).+?\b)[\s\S]*?([a-z0-9.,-]+)\)})
```

Comment: Very cool. Btw: I used``\\href{http://www.bibleserver.com/text/SLT/$2$4 $6}{$1}``. For learning how regex work, how would you have done it, if there was no vgl. restriction?

Comment: just make the `vgl\.` part optional.. by replacing it with `(?:vgl\.)?` check the update..